# OpenGL ES 2.0 texture as 2D LUT table

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to implement color space conversion from CIEL*a*b* to sRGB with 2D LUT tables on OpenGL. I have generated LUT table with Python like this:

```
    for l in range(0, 256):
    for a in range(0, 256):
        for cb in range(0, 256):

            lf = l / 255. * 100.00000386666655
            af = a / 255. * (86.1827164205346 + 98.23431188800402) - 86.1827164205346
            bf = cb / 255. * (107.8601617541481 + 94.47797505367028) - 107.8601617541481

            x, y, z = lab2xyz(lf, af, bf)
            r, g, b = xyz2rgb(x, y, z)

            r_int = int(r)
            g_int = int(g)
            b_int = int(b)

            if r_int < 0:
                r_int = 0
            if r_int > 255:
                r_int = 255
            if g_int < 0:
                g_int = 0
            if g_int > 255:
                g_int = 255
            if b_int < 0:
                b_int = 0
            if b_int > 255:
                b_int = 255

            data[a + 256 * (l // 16), cb + 256 * (l % 16)] = [r_int, g_int, b_int, 255]

img = smp.toimage(data)
img.save("lab2rgb.png", "png")
```

[image: 2D LUT]

It's 4096 by 4096 pixels.

In my Android app I load all my textures with this code:

```
        GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GLES20.GL_LINEAR);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D,
                GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GLES20.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, img, 0);
```

In my Fragment Shader I use them like this:

```
void main() {
vec3 xyz;

vec4 rgba = texture2D(uTexture, vTexPosition);

srgb2xyz(rgba, xyz);
vec3 lab;

xyz2lab(xyz, lab);

highp vec2 newCoordinates;

int l_int = int(lab.x / 100.0 * 255.0);
int a_int = int((lab.y + 86.1827164205346) / (86.1827164205346 + 98.23431188800402) * 255.0);
int b_int = int((lab.z + 107.8601617541481) / (107.8601617541481 + 94.47797505367028) * 255.0);

newCoordinates.x = float(b_int + 256 * modulus(l_int, 16)) / 4095.0;
newCoordinates.y = 1.0 - (float(a_int + 256 * (l_int / 16)) / 4095.0);

rgba = texture2D(lab2rgbLUT, newCoordinates);

gl_FragColor = rgba;
}
```

I assume that OpenGL ES 2.0 textures have coordinate system where x, y belong to the line segment [0, 1]. That's why I divide my coordinates by 4095.

However, I get wrong colors doing conversion this way. Everything works fine if I do straight forward conversion LUT->XYZ->RGB.

Am I missing something? Is it a proper way to using LUT tables? Is there any other solution? I tried to create an array of vec3 of size 4096*4096. But it says array is too large.

Comment: Couple of thoughts. Are you using high precision in your fragment shader? You're going to need it for maths like that and OpenGLES2 fragment shaders default to mediump (more or less 16-bit half-precision floats). Linear filtering is going to allow bleeding between the different 'cells' in your lab2rgb texture. Point filtering might be better, or an Array Texture or 3D texture might be a better fit if you can get away with using OpenGL ES 3.

Comment: @Columbo Yes, I’m using highp in my fragment shader. Using OpenGL ES 3 is not an option for me. Unfortunately.

Comment: @Columbo just tried changing GL_LINEAR to GL_NEAREST, didn't make any improvements.